# Looking for free tool that works as notebook for programmers

Tags: knowledge-organization

I am looking for a notebook style app available online and offline where I can store code snippets interspersed with notes and other related info.
Might get Quiver but just curious if there is anything else notebook style out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may wish to take a look at [Jupyter Notebooks](http://jupyter.org/), possibly in conjunction with an online version control system such as GitHib or BitBucket.

Jupyter allows you to store in it's notebook files, (.ipynb files), a set of cells each of which contain either MarkDown, (which is rendered to HTML when you are viewing rather than editing the cells just like here on StackOverflow), including links *possibly to other notebooks*, embedding Images & Media, etc. Or Code. You can even embed YouTube Videos!

Each notebook you create is for a specified kernel out or those that you have installed, (of which there a multitude listed [here](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/wiki/Jupyter-kernels)). Some of the possible kernels include Python *(always available)*, FORTRAN, Spark, SAS, R, Julia, Haskell, Ruby, Bash, JavaScript, CoffeeScript, GO, Scala, Erlang, Perl, PHP, PowerShell, the list goes on.

Code cells are Syntax highlighted and are **executable** *on any platform that has the required kernel & tools* with the output of running the code embedded in the page once the code has been run. Depending on the selected kernel you can even have some code cells in other languages than the notebooks selected kernel by using [cell magics](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#cell-magics), *note that you do need the specified language installed.*.

The Jupyter notebooks, *including the results*, can be version controlled and some online services such as GitHub render them for display. They can also be saved to web pages, (HTML), or pdf file.

Jupyter is Free, Gatis & Open Source (MIT Licence) as are the majority of the kernels. It can run on a number of platforms including Windows, MacOS, Linux, docker, [MS Azure](https://notebooks.azure.com/), [AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mxnet/latest/dg/setup-jupyter.html), etc.

See [A gallery of interesting Jupyter Notebooks](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/wiki/A-gallery-of-interesting-Jupyter-Notebooks) and the [Notebook Gallery](http://nb.bianp.net/sort/views/) for great examples of linking a multitude of Jupyter Notebooks together.

Comment: It looks a little out of comfort zone but I am going to try this alongside a tutorial I found that just mentioned this software!

Answer (score 2):

check out [Boostnote](https://boostnote.io/), it's free and got lots of nice features and great code support.  I also use [Bear](https://bear-writer.com) (it's free and also has an upgrade purchase but the free version is fine.  You just get a few more themes and iCloud sync with the purchase, which is not needed when you can just save your notes on Dropbox, Google Drive or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Zeppelin](https://zeppelin.apache.org) is a web based programming notebook with interpreters for several languages. It is oriented for data analysis.